# Postgres left join many-to-many on ID with rightside results as array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, left-join, aggregate

I thought this would be obvious but I am not able to figure this out.

I have the following many to many setup.
A collection of images can hold a series of tags.

```
-- Images.
CREATE TABLE ImageContent (
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title TEXT NOT NULL,
    Description TEXT,
    ImageUrl TEXT NOT NULL,
    CreationDate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The tags are stored in a seperate table.

```sql
-- All tags to be used.
CREATE TABLE ContentTags (
    Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    TagName TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

The tags and images are tied together with the following joining table.

```sql
-- Many-to-many tags relation to a image
CREATE TABLE ImageTags (
    imageId INTEGER,
    TagID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (imageID) REFERENCES ImageContent
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (TagID) REFERENCES ContentTags
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (imageId, TagID)
);
```

Now I wish to get the image rows with the associated tag names in a single column.

| Id | Title | Description | ImageUrl | CreationDate | Tags |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | bar | /baz/img.jpg | 2022-05-07 | abstract, oil, duck |

Currently I am getting a row per tag as result and then using a groupby in code.
Appending groupby to the current query itself throws a error.

```sql
SELECT img.*, c.tagname
FROM imagecontent img
JOIN imagetags i on img.id = i.imageid
JOIN contenttags c on c.id = i.tagid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join to the result of an aggregation:

```
select img.*, t.tags
from imagecontent img
  left join (
    select it.imageid, string_agg(ct.tagname, ',') as tags  
    from imagetags it
      join contenttags ct on it.tagid = ct.id
    group by it.imageid
  ) t on t.imageid = img.id
order by img.id
```